# VBA Excel Code Errors IF Else Between a Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a simple VBA code that requires a user input of a number between -9 and +9. Once the user inputs a number, the code will pull data from specific columns, related to the input number, from one sheet into a new sheet. I have the code written out but I am having a problem with the If Else function. I get an error that reads "Compile error: Syntax error". If I get rid of the Else function the code works great for anything greater than or equal to 0, but I need to have the ability to pull data related to the negative inputs. Should I not use If Else for this code?

```
Sub AA()
On Error Resume Next
er = Sheets("D2").Range("AA65536").End(xlUp).Row
ec = Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
r = 3
Range("A3:IV65536").ClearContents
For i = 504 To er
 a = Sheets("D2").Cells(i, "AA")
If WorksheetFunction.IsErr(a) Then a = 0
If a >= Cells(2, 1).Value Then
    For j = 2 To ec
        f = Cells(1, j)
        Cells(r, j) = Sheets("D2").Cells(i, f)
    Next j
    r = r + 1

Else a < Cells(2, 1).Value Then
    For j = 2 To ec
        f = Cells(1, j)
        Cells(r, j) = Sheets("D2").Cells(i, f)
    Next j
    r = r + 1
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have a `Else` with a condition, you have to use `ElseIf` rather than `Else`

Comment: And please, remove this infamous `On Error Resume Next`. It silently steps over all runtime errors and this will make it nearly impossilbe to trap any error

Comment: Tried both Else and ElseIf but both times when I inputted a number like +2 it ended up pulling all the data from -9 to +9.

Comment: Use the debugger to understand how your code works. Set a breakpoint (F9) to the beginning of the code and step thru the routine with F8. See what happens and try to understand why. Think about your logic and adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

1. Option Explicit - Helps you to declare all variables
2. Use *Elseif a < Cells(2, 1).Value* instead of *Else a < Cells(2, 1).Value* **OR** just replace  *Else a < Cells(2, 1).Value* with *Else*
3. Variables referring to Last row or last column declare *as long*
4. No need to use *On Error Resume Next*
5. If you want to loop range use * for each* or *For i=1 to *

**Code guidelines:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long, Row As Long, Column As Long
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Set the worksheet you want to use

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<- Find last row of column A sheet1
        LastColumn = .Cells(7, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column '<- Find last column of row 7 sheet1

        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow) '<- Set range

        'Method 1
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Value = 1 Then
            ElseIf cell.Value = 2 Then
            End If
        Next cell

        'Method 2
        For Row = 2 To LastRow '<- Loop from row 2 to last row
            For Column = 1 To LastColumn '<- Loop from column 1 to last column
            Next Column
        Next Row

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @soup12 i try to provide some demo code to help you

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
Else a < Cells(2, 1).Value Then
```

with:

```
Else
```

Comment: Tried doing this and what ended up happening is when I input a specific number ie 2 it gives me data from -9 to +9.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting rid of the `Else` and just using another `If` Statement?  Also I would get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` especially if you are still testing your code out.

```
Sub AA()
On Error Resume Next
er = Sheets("D2").Range("AA65536").End(xlUp).Row
ec = Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
r = 3
Range("A3:IV65536").ClearContents
For i = 504 To er
 a = Sheets("D2").Cells(i, "AA")
If WorksheetFunction.IsErr(a) Then a = 0
If a >= Cells(2, 1).Value Then
    For j = 2 To ec
        f = Cells(1, j)
        Cells(r, j) = Sheets("D2").Cells(i, f)
    Next j
    r = r + 1
End if

If a < Cells(2, 1).Value Then
    For j = 2 To ec
        f = Cells(1, j)
        Cells(r, j) = Sheets("D2").Cells(i, f)
    Next j
    r = r + 1
End If
Next i
End Sub
```